# Fill in all dates in certain date ranges from another using calendar table

Tags: sql

I've got two date tables in a database I'm writing a query for. There's a dbo.days (calendar) table and a dbo.holidays table.

I need a simple list of all unique days that are holidays, so the output of my query should be something like this:

```
01-01-2014
01-02-2014
18-04-2014
20-04-2014
26-04-2014
27-04-2014
```

Now, the calender table has all dates, but as a second column only lists whether it's a working day (no differentiation between weekend days and holidays)

And the holiday table looks a little like this:

```
Description           DateFrom      DateTo
Holiday description   01-01-2014    01-02-2014
Holiday description   18-04-2014    18-04-2014
Holiday description   20-04-2014    21-04-2014
Holiday description   26-04-2014    26-04-2014
```

Since this table allows for date ranges, a can of worms open. I can't just select all DateFrom days. In reality, no holiday (Netherlands here) lasts for longer than two days, so just selecting all DateFroms and adding the few DateTo dates gets me the list that I want. But in the case someone would like to have a month long new years day holiday, I want to see 01/01, 02/01, 03/01, 04/01, etc.
The query below retrieves the dates, but doesn't seem to work the way I envision it. Through SO, I found [this article](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3), and the last query listed there somewhat applies to my situation. I just can't get it to work in my situation.

Maybe it's a bit of a beginner mistake, but I hope someone is able to help me out.

```
Select convert(varchar,d.Date, 105) from dbo.Days d
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Holidays H on d.Date = h.DateFrom
where d.Date >= h.DateFrom or d.Date <= h.DateTo
```

Comment: You might be better off with a holiday field in your calendar table.  Alternatively, if you want a holiday table, just have two fields, the date and the holiday.  If anything lasts more than a day, enter multiple records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want to do

```
SELECT convert(varchar,d.Date, 105) FROM dbo.Days d
JOIN dbo.Holidays H ON d.Date BETWEEN h.DateFrom AND h.DateTo
```